# How to do math in a java generic method?

Tags: java, arrays, object, math

I'm porting some image processing code from C++ to Java.  My C++ code has template classes that define mixed-mode image arithmetic.  I'm trying to do the same in Java but it's clear that I don't understand the concepts needed to do it.  Currently, I'm trying to write a generic method.

```
private void DoMyRoutine()
{
    float[] data = {1.1f,2.2f,3.3f};
    Float[] fArr = new Float[data.length]; // Is there a better way to do this?
    for(int i = 0; i< data.length;i++)
    {
        fArr[i] = data[i];
    }
    fArr = Test(fArr);
}
```

//*********************************************************************************************

```
private <T> T[] Test( T[] myData)
{
    Float inc = new Float(2.0f);
    for(int i=0;i<myData.length;i++)
    {
        // I can see the myData array values in the debugger
        // This clearly doesn't work, is there a method"
        myData[i] = inc; 
    }
    return myData;
}
```

Am I even on the right track? I'm relatively new to Java and still struggling with some of the concepts and syntax.

Comment: it would be a lot easier to help if you would explain what are you trying to do

Comment: Basically Java generics are nothing like C++ templates.  You really cannot translate one to the other.  As Eugene said, the only way to help you is to give us you're actual use case.

Comment: Why does your C++ code have template classes?

Comment: I guess other answers are: 1) Probably no you are not on the right track, the code above looks kinda bad.  And 2) we can't tell for sure from this brief example, you'll have to explain what is really going on.

Comment: I presented a simple code for a generic method to process a variety of image data types.  Eventually, a successful Test() method syntax will be used to write a variety of different algorithms that operate on 8 and 16, and 32-bit integer, float, and double data.  Yes, the presented code is not good but that's why I'm here.  The C++ template classes were very effective for doing this.